# I want to put the image and text into the list box item(C# wpf)

Tags: c#, image, text, listbox, wpf-controls

The image of the list box item is too large.
[image]

I want to make this an item of constant height. Like the picture below.
[image]

This is my Code -

xaml:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListBox_Drop" DragEnter="ListBox_DragEnter" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding Path}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

cs:

```
class VideoListing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
List<VideoListing> list = new List<VideoListing>();
    public VideoPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list.Add(new VideoListing()
        {
            Name = "hello",
            Path = @"C:\Users\johndoe\Desktop\Screenshot.png",
        });
        listBox.Items.Add(list);
    }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: @TaW Thanks, I changed the question title.

Comment: WPF should NOT be in the title. It should be a Tag! (changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set either the Height or the MaxHeight properties on the Image control. Since you say you want a "constant height" then set the height of the image and tell it to scale the source appropriately.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding Path}" Height="64" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the listView control in your application and use imagelist control to hold many images and set image index in a listview control.
I think it's too simple